# How to resolve false "Object is possibly 'undefined'" in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a function that will check if a property of an object (data in dataHandler) is undefined:

```
function getDataHandlerFeedback(
  dataHandler: { data?: any; },
): undefined | string {
  const isLoading = dataHandler.data === undefined;
  if (isLoading) {
    return 'Loading...';
  }
  return undefined
}
```

Then in another function I will use that object based on the result of the first function:

```
export default function ExampleComponent() {
  const myDataHandler = someSWRHook();
  const dataFeedback = getDataHandlerFeedback(myDataHandler);
  
  // Early return if data is undefined
  if (dataFeedback) {
    return dataFeedback;
  }
  
  // At this point "myDataHandler.data" is definitely not undefined,
  // Still I get "Object is possibly 'undefined'."
  return myDataHandler.data.map(() => {})
}
```

Is there any way around this false positive without doing the type check myself (with`!` or ts-ignore)?

Comment: `sitesDataHandler` is not defined, you have only defined `myDataHandler `. You have only checked `sitesDataHandler` but have not checked `myDataHandler`

Comment: @RickyMo That's a typo. I've somehow missed that while simplifying the example to post here. I've fixed that, the issue still exists.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

The reason your code does not work is because [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) doesn't work on optional types. The most direct quote is in the section on [in-operator narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing). The quote is only discussing the in-operator, but I think this is true in general:

> optional properties will exist in both sides for narrowing

There are many solutions (see below). My recommended one is a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) resolving to a [required utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype) as follows:

```
type X = { data?: string }

const isData = (x: X): x is Required<X> => !!x.data

const test = (x: X) => {
  if (isData(x)) {
    x.data // data: string
  } else {
    x.data // data?: string | undefined
  }
}
```

---

Here is the longer-winded research I did on this.

Your type is explicitly defined as optional, and so it always will be. You can see this in your own function by inspecting `dataHandler.data` within the if-block of `getDataHandlerFeedback`. Or here below:

```
const test1 = (x: { data?: any }) => {
  if (x.data) {
    x.data // data?: any
  } else {
    x.data // data?: any
  }
}
```

If your type was, for example, a non-optional union of primitives, it would work:

```
const test2 = (x: { data: string | undefined }) => {
  if (x.data) {
    x.data // data: string
  } else {
    x.data // data: string | undefined (because !!'' == false)
  }

  if (typeof x.data === 'string') {
    x.data // data: string
  } else {
    x.data // data: undefined
  }
}
```

I was curious if you could truthy-check a union of complex types but TS will error before you have a chance. This make sense because the type either explicitly has `data` or explicitly does not. You can, however, narrow with the `in` operator, which is a solution to your problem. That is: change your type to a union and you can then use the in-operator:

```
const test3 = (x: { data: string } | {}) => {
  if (x.data) {
  }
  // Property 'data' does not exist on type '{} | { data: string }'.
  //   Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'

  if ("data" in x) {
    x.data // data: string
  } else {
    x.data // Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'
  }
}
```

I was then curious if you could type-check a union type of non-primitives through [control-flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) instead of [type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). It seems like it won't work across some functions:

```
type No = {}
type Yes = { data: string }
const test4Check = (x: No | Yes) => {
  if ('data' in x) {
    x.data // data: string
    return undefined
  } else {
    x.data // Property 'data' does not exist on type 'No'
    return 'Loading...'
  }
}

const test4 = (x: No | Yes) => {
  const y = test4Check(x)
  if (y) {
    x.data // Property 'data' does not exist on type 'No | Yes'...
  } else {
    x.data // Property 'data' does not exist on type 'No | Yes'...
  }
}
```

But it will work across carefully constructed, well-typed functions:

```
const test5Check = (x: No | Yes): [true, Yes] | [false, No] => {
  if ('data' in x) {
    return [true, x]
  } else {
    return [false, x]
  }
}

const test5 = (x: No | Yes) => {
  const [bool, y] = test5Check(x)
  if (bool) {
    y.data // data: string
  } else {
    y.data // Property 'data' does not exist on type 'No'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want seems to be [User-defined type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). However, the docs doesn't mention a way to specify a fine-tuned predicate such as `dataHandler["data"] is ...`. Therefore, TypeScript won't understand that if `dataFeedback` has a value, `dataHandler.data` must be undefined and vice versa.

For your code to work correctly, the simplest way is to inline that condition in `ExampleComponent`:

```
function ExampleComponent() {
  const myDataHandler = someSWRHook();
  
  if (!myDataHandler.data) {
    return 'Loading...';
  }
  
  return myDataHandler.data.map(() => {});
}
```